# How can i make drop down values Selected using Javascript by jsonencode data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

In my html form i have 9 drop down values which if user action is Edit then it will fetch the values from database and return in the jsonencode format.as below,

> JSON DATA

```
 [{"ed_gender":"Male","ed_blood_group":"A-","ed_marital_status":"Single","ed_branch_id":"11","ed_desig_id":"1","ed_job_type":"Permanent","ed_pay_mode":"Cheque"}]
```

> HTML

```
 <select name="ed_gender" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
 </select>

 <select name="ed_marital_status" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Single">Single</option>
    <option value="Married">Married</option>
 </select>
```

I tried few lines of code using php its actually works but i am trying using javascript.

> PHP

```
 <select name="ed_marital_status" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option <?php if($ed_marital_status=="Single") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="Single">Single</option>
    <option <?php if($ed_marital_status=="Married") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="Married">Married</option>
 </select>
```

So here Behave i have to extract the json values and make dropdown values has "Selected" on page loads.

EDITED :

> JSON DATA

```
 [{"ed_branch_id":"11","ed_desig_id":"1"}]
```

> HTML

```
 <select name="ed_job_location" class="form-control">
     <option value="">Select</option>
      <?php
       foreach($get_branches as $branches){
              $branches_id   = $branches->b_id;
              $branches_name = $branches->b_name; 
              $branches_code = $branches->b_code; 
              echo "<option value='$branches_id||$branches_name||$branches_code'>$branches_name</option>";
       }?>
  </select>

  <select name="ed_desig_id" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <?php
      foreach($get_designation as $designations){
             $designations_id   = $designations->d_id;
             $designations_name = $designations->d_designation; 
             $designations_code = $designations->d_code; 
             echo "<option value='$designations_id||$designations_code'>$designations_name</option>";
       }?>
   </select>
```

Here from above json, i am getting only branch id and desig id, But here i have value with || symbol in the select option, so i need to find particular id and show it in the drop down.

Comment: Hi you mean you want to use Json data insert to  Html select  , are you

Comment: yes exactly but not insert i need to select the value of drop down @ willie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the array of `json` objects and fill each element value by selecting it through its name:

```js
var json = [{"ed_gender":"Male","ed_blood_group":"A-","ed_marital_status":"Single","ed_branch_id":"11","ed_desig_id":"1","ed_job_type":"Permanent","ed_pay_mode":"Cheque"}];

$(document).ready(function(){
   $.each(json[0], function(index, element) {

       $("[name="+index + "]").val(element);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="ed_gender" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
 </select>

 <select name="ed_marital_status" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Single">Single</option>
    <option value="Married">Married</option>
 </select>
```

EDIT:

You can explicitly set the values to cover the special case of branch values concatenation with `||` outside the loop, as long as the values are within the `json` data returned :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       $("[name=ed_job_location]").val(json[0].branches_id + "||" + json[0].branches_name + "||" + json[0].branches_code);

    });
```

Comment: Hi KAD, thanks a lot for above answer, I have another doubt, if my option values as this type  "<option value='$branches_id||$branches_name||$branches_code'>$branches_name</option>" its not working for that

Comment: You need to cover all the cases you have, that's the key step though.. Each value might fill an element in a specific way, the field may be something other than selectbox... Try to handle all cases, or post more html to verify what you really want.

Comment: ya its working perfect  +1 one vote :-)  , thanks a lot